# Finding $||Px||$ where P is the orthogonal projection on $L=\langle 2e_4+ e_5, e_1 \rangle \subseteq l^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, orthogonality

I am struggling to do this question. I have been told to use the lecture notes to find the formula for $Px$, but I cannot! Hopefully, by seeing one example with a little bit of explanation. I will know how to do all these questions.

Let $L = \langle 2 e_4 + e_5, e_1 \rangle \subseteq l^2$. For $x=(8,2,1,7,6,5,4,3,3,0,0,0,...)$, find $||Px||$, where $P$ is the orthogonal projection on L. Enter your answer to two decimal places. I know that $||Px||\leq||x||$ and I have a solution that the answer is 12, but the way how to do it seems to be evading me.

Comment: Suppose you had an orthonormal basis for $L$, say, $v_1,v_2$. Then the projection is $Px=(x,v_1)v_1+(x,v_2)v_2$, so the norm is $\sqrt{(x,v_1)^2+(x,v_2)^2}$. Now just compute.

Comment: So can we choose $v_1=\frac{2e_4 +e_5}{5}$ and $v_2=e_1$. So we have that Px=4v_1+8v_2. We do not get 12? x

Comment: No, you must normalize $v_1$. Divide it by its norm, which is $\sqrt{5}$, not $5$.